# AngularJS jasmine maven plugin preload sources paths issue

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, jasmine-maven-plugin

I'm wondering why some paths to javascript libs are working in the preload sources section and some aren't.

E.g.

```
<preloadSources>
  <source>${project.basedir}/src/test/webapp/js/lib/jquery-1.8.3.js</source>
  <source>${project.basedir}/src/test/webapp/js/lib/angular-mocks.js</source>
  <source>${project.basedir}/src/test/webapp/js/lib/jasmine-jquery-1.4.2.js</source>
  <source>${project.basedir}/src/test/webapp/js/lib/angular-resource.js</source>
  <source>${project.basedir}/src/test/webapp/js/lib/angular.js</source>
</preloadSources>
```

works, but

```
<preloadSources>
  <source>${project.basedir}/src/test/webapp/js/lib/jquery-1.8.3.js</source>
  <source>${project.basedir}/src/test/webapp/js/lib/angular-mocks.js</source>
  <source>${project.basedir}/src/test/webapp/js/lib/jasmine-jquery-1.4.2.js</source>
  <source>${project.basedir}/src/test/webapp/js/lib/angular-resource.js</source>
  <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/somePath/system/apps/javascripts/angular.js</source>
</preloadSources>
```

doesn't as jasmine complains about not knowing anything about the keywords "module" or  "angular". Is this a known issue? I didn't find anything related in the project's bug tracker.

Comment: Even now i started working, facing the same issue, Did you found any work around for the problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to load angular.js before you load angular-mocks.js or angular-resource.js because both angular-mocks.js and angular-resource.js depend on angular.js.

Comment: So why does it work in the first case then? As there angular.js is also the last loaded library.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue, it seems that the path is build once. If you specify another directory it crashes.